# How to delete a row as indicated in a cell in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

What I want to do:
I write a row number in a cell, let's say F1, and the value is 9.
I want to add a button that calls a script that will delete the line as I wrote it into the cell, so in this example, line 9.

So I start with:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sheet = s.getSheetByName('Books');
var row = sheet.getRange('F1');
```

However this:

```
sheet.deleteRow(row.getValue());
```

will give an out of bounds error. getDisplayValue does not work as well and putting it into an parseint doesn't work either.

The 9 hardcoded
`sheet.deleteRow(9);`
works of course.

I also debbuged and did a
`sheet.getRange('G1').setValue(row.getValue());`
to verify that the 9 is indeed there, which it is, the 9 will be copied to cell G1.

`sheet.getRange('A'+row.getValue()+':J'+row.getValue()).clearContent();`
meanwhile will have it treat it as a A:J and delete every line not just one. Doing toString after getValue did also not change anything.

What am I missing here to turn the cell value into a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet.deleteRow(value of F1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value) {
    sh.deleteRow(e.value)
  }
}
```

Cannot call this function from script editor must save in project and edit F1 of Your Sheet.  You also need to edit line 3 and add the name of the appropriate sheet.

Using a checkbox for a button:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("Gate1")
    e.range.setValue("FALSE")
    sh.deleteRow(sh.getRange("F1").getValue());
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Does "Cannot call this function from script editor" mean, it's impossible to do it via a button click? With an onEdit it would immediately delete it as soon as a value is inserted to the field, rather than when it's clicked. (So no time to double check.)

Comment: Yes but instead of putting a button somewhere you could put a checkbox there instead and use the checkboxes as a button.

Comment: .... that's a brilliantly simple workaround. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: If you wish to use a checkbox as a button then don't forget to reset the checkbox with e.range.setValue("FALSE"); everytime.

Comment: I just realized when trying that the checkbox only helps for setting it into a sort of edit mode, but would not help for being the trigger. (Which would mean if you made a typo when editing you can't double check anymore.) Because if clicking the checkbox cell is the trigger then the e parameter from onEdit would get the checkbox cell and not the input cell for the row number to be deleted. Trying to get access to that value would get me to the premise problem again.

Comment: You need learn how to think outside the box a bit.  Consider the most recent modification to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the demo! You were right, I got stuck on a wrong idea. (I thought getvalue wouldn't work with deleteRow, since that was the single line that didn't work in the botton-invoked script). I also didn't know about toasts, yet. That was a great bonus.

Comment: Yes toasts are very useful when debugging onEdit() functions.  You can comment them out when not debugging